# How to convert points to lines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion

I want to convert these points to lines, however they are not sorted sequentially along a line (by ID or FID), i.e. the converted lines zig-zag across the obvious trail of points.

How can I join these point trails based on proximity to points?

I don't have access to the Near (Analysis) tool, which I thought might help me move froward.

[image: Example]

Comment: To begin with, your points will need an attribute field identifying them as part of the same line.  I believe after something like the QGIS PointsToPaths plugins would work.

Comment: Given that one answerer was criticized for mentioning it, I suggest inserting "using `PointsToLine_management()`" between "i.e." and " the converted lines zig"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. One approach is to convert this to raster and then extract contours
2. Another is to find the buffer for each point;Dissolve those buffers to get a narrow polygon;Find the center line of each dissolved polygon.

Comment: I just wanted to alert you that we had discussion about [why this answer was set to Community Wiki](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3948/why-is-this-post-marked-as-community-wiki) in Meta.  If you intended it to be, then just edit and reset that, perhaps along with a message to say why.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a line identifier.
A buffer will probably do what you need, with dissolve. Then you can spatially join the buffer polys back to the points and transfer the buffer fid across.
Then you need to sequence them in some way.
The points all seem to go NE-SW, so perhaps ordering on the Y coord will get you a sequence. Apply this as an index to the points. Then use the Points To Lines tool.

Answer (score 0):

we have once Geoprocessing tool **Point to Line** in arcgis use once i think this is useful to you

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003s000000

Comment: -1 It sounds like the asker already tried this but it did not work.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer, but could do with some expansion of details. Such as first you would have to add something to identify the points as belonging to a particular line, and possibly a particular sequence (sort_field). This is essentially the same as Neil's later posted answer, but note the detail he has provided in using the tool.